# Count the number of distinct values of each row (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

How can I create a new column that returns the number of distinct values in each row inside my table?  For instance,

```
ID   Description   Pay1    Pay2   Pay3    #UniquePays     
1    asdf1         10      20     10      2
2    asdf2         0       10     20      3
3    asdf3         100     100    100     1
4    asdf4                 0      10      3
```

The query may return >1million rows so it needs to be somewhat efficient.  There are 8 'Pay' columns in total, which are either NULL or an integer. Also note that '0' should be counted distinct from NULL.

The most I've been able to accomplish thus far (which I just realized isn't even accurate) is counting the total number of Pay entries in each row:

```
nvl(length(length(Pay1)),0)
+nvl(length(length(Pay2)),0)
+nvl(length(length(Pay3)),0) "NumPays"
```

The typical row only has 4 of the 8 columns populated, with the rest being null, and the max integer in the Pay column is '999' (hence the length-length conversion attempt..)

My SQL skills are primitive but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your current output the result of a query that does a pivot? If so it would be easier to start from the base data. Otherwise it looks like you might have denormalised data.

Comment: Your table is poorly designed. You shouldn't have 8 columns for the Pay, you should insert one row for each pay.

Comment: Are two NULL considered "the same"?

Comment: The Pay columns represent different types/categories of payment (not historical/transactional payments being made), hence the reason for there being 8 instances of them, so they are not the same.

And yes, multiple NULL values should be counted as the same.

Comment: @AlexPoole - with what you said... the first thought, of course, was to UNPIVOT (one way or another, depending on Oracle version); but if that's how the rows are stored, then unpivoting would be quite inefficient, better to write long and ugly code that just processes each row as it comes in. Of course, if the "input" is the result of a PIVOT operation, that's another matter.

Comment: Re:pivot.  The 8 columns are stored that way in the table, so the current query does not have to join to create them, it simply returns the columns.

Comment: @mathguy - yes, that was what I was getting at *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split out each value into its own row (like it should have been stored in the first place), then `union` then up and (since `union` discards duplicates) just count the rows:

```
select id, description, count(*) unique_pays from (
    select id, description, nvl(pay1, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay2, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay3, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay4, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay5, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay6, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay7, -1) from mytable
    union select id, description, nvl(pay8, -1) from mytable
) x
group by id, description
```

I changed nulls into -1 so they would participate cleanly in the deduping.

Comment: This will read a table with millions of rows, eight times. OP was concerned about efficiency...

Comment: @mathguy then maybe OP should fix his schema. Your point has merit, but "millions of rows" is not that many these days (100's of millions is getting large). This may perform OK anyway - let's see which answer OP chooses.

Comment: Per my comment on original post, the 'Pay' columns are not historical but instead categorical.  Think of them as 'Tiers' instead of 'payment history'.  They're different from another, hence the reason for there being 8 of them (and only 8).

Comment: @KevinT Then you should store it in a table as `(ReferenceId, PaymentType, value)` with a unique constraint `(ReferenceId, PaymentType)`

Comment: Again, they're not pay_ments_ but rather 'available tiers'.  I should have represented them as such in my original post to avoid confusion.  The tables are set up correctly, I'm just not doing a very good job representing the simplistic version of them correctly.

Comment: @KevinT I'm not exactly sure how that changes anything, just replace `PaymentType` with `AvailableTier` instead. I'm sure you get the point I'm trying to make, but pretty much every time you wonder how you can aggregate on columns instead of on rows, the answer is "You should have done a better job at designing your table". I fail to see how your case is any different, but you're the one who has to deal with it.

Comment: @VincentSavard - I know nothing firsthand, but I learned from others (this specific one, perhaps, on OTN): Even if those were stored in the "ref_no, tier, amount" format, one might still create a multi-column table like the OP has, for analysis purposes - perhaps as a materialized view. Queries like the OP needs actually run much faster when the data is already organized by ref_no (than needing to PIVOT every time such a query is run).

Comment: @mathguy Which is an optimization concern you have after you evaluated that the benefits outweight the disadvantages, which is clearly not what happened here. If that's the route OP wants to go, then that's his call, he can pick any answer here and go with it. But when I read "My SQL skills are primitive", my first reaction is to help him identify design flaws, not to encourage him to go down this route.

Comment: I'm not the designer of the >100TB database being used for 50+million users with thousands of tables ;)  I'm simply an end-user trying to pull a particular set of data from it. I realize that even explaining the 'pay' columns in terms of 'tiers' still isn't quite accurate, as the tiers aren't just simple 'numerical' or 'integral' tiers, but rather categorical in nature.  Still not quite sure how to fully describe it, so my over-simplification of the system is inherently flawed. I appreciate the help/follow up with this query though, and very impressed with stack community's thoroughness =)

Comment: @VincentSavard - I wasn't offering that as an argument in favor of building a table that way. Rather, some posters questioned the wisdom of EVER having a table in that format. I was simply sharing what I have learned - that such a format, which often may violate common table design principles, is in fact built on purpose, sometimes, for the reason I explained. My purpose was simply to point out that tables in that format aren't necessarily a bad thing - they may even be a good thing, done by experts, for a very good reason.

Comment: Just wanted to add this method appears to work as well! Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin How did it perform? How did other answers perform?

Comment: 1.5 seconds to complete on ~100k row results.. so.. excellent!  Both this and mathguy's 'case-when' method are simple+valid solutions (I'm still trying to fully comprehend the logic behind this solution, but the query is 'prettier' IMO).

Comment: @kevin interesting. Another thing to consider is that this query uses only standard SQL and so is entirely portable to any other database.

Comment: Ended up using this as the final - I get how it works.  Simplicity > *

Answer (score 3):

If you have, or can create, a user-defined table of numbers, you could use create a collection, use [the `set` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions163.htm#SQLRF06308) to get rid of duplicates, and then use [the `cardinality` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions022.htm#SQLRF06305) to count the remaining values:

```
cardinality(set(t_num(pay1, pay2, pay3))) as uniquepays
```

To include all eight of your columns, just add the extra column names to list passed to the `tnum()` constructor.

```
cardinality(set(t_num(pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4, pay5, pay6, pay7, pay8))) as uniquepays
```

Demo with your sample table generated as a CTE:

```
create type t_num as table of number
/

with t (ID, Description, Pay1, Pay2, Pay3) as (
  select 1, 'asdf1', 10, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select 2, 'asdf2', 0, 10, 20 from dual
  union all select 3, 'asdf3', 100, 100, 100 from dual
  union all select 4, 'asdf4', null, 0, 10 from dual
)
select id, description, pay1, pay2, pay3,
  cardinality(set(t_num(pay1, pay2, pay3))) as uniquepays
from t
order by id;

        ID DESCR       PAY1       PAY2       PAY3 UNIQUEPAYS
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 asdf1         10         20         10          2
         2 asdf2          0         10         20          3
         3 asdf3        100        100        100          1
         4 asdf4                     0         10          3
```

Whether that is efficient enough with millions of rows will need to be tested.

Comment: I like how your use of `CARDINALITY` handles the nulls the way the OP wants.  Personally, I wouldn't count a null pay value toward `UNIQUEPAYS`, but the question is the question.

Comment: I think `VALUES()` is better than `from dual union all`

Comment: @Hogan - as far as I'm aware only SQL Server and PostgreSQL support a construct like `values(1, 'asdf1', 10, 20, 10), (2, 'asdf2', ...), ...`. If that's what you mean. Oracle only allows `values` in an insert statement, and even then only a single.. er.. set of values. Another part of the SQL standard Oracle doesn't support?

Comment: I just did a google search http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj11277.html

Comment: @Hogan - OK, then JavaDB supports it too. Oracle RDBMS still doesn't though, unfortunately, [even in 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions.htm#SQLRF004). (Oracle's doc site covers all their products, including MySQL, which also causes much confusion.) Interestingly one of the contributors here [requested it be added last year](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13697).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one relatively simple way:

```
CREATE TYPE number_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

with t (ID, Description, Pay1, Pay2, Pay3) as (
  select 1, 'asdf1', 10, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select 2, 'asdf2', 0, 10, 20 from dual
  union all select 3, 'asdf3', 100, 100, 100 from dual
  union all select 4, 'asdf4', null, 0, 10 from dual
)
SELECT id,
       description,
       pay1,
       pay2,
       pay3,
       (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT NVL (TO_CHAR (COLUMN_VALUE), '#NULL#')) 
        FROM TABLE (number_list (pay1, pay2, pay3))) uniquepays
FROM   t;

        ID DESCR       PAY1       PAY2       PAY3 UNIQUEPAYS
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 asdf1         10         20         10          2
         2 asdf2          0         10         20          3
         3 asdf3        100        100        100          1
         4 asdf4                     0         10          3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that reads the base table just once, and takes advantage of the data being organized in rows already. (Unpivoting would be inefficient, since this information would be lost resulting in massive additional work.)

It assumes all `NULL`s are counted as the same. If instead they should be considered different from each other, change the `-1` in `nvl` to distinct values: `-1` for `Pay1`, `-2` for `Pay2`, etc.

```
with
     inputs( ID, Description, Pay1, Pay2, Pay3 ) as (     
       select 1, 'asdf1',                   10,  20,  10 from dual union all
       select 2, 'asdf2',                    0,  10,  20 from dual union all
       select 3, 'asdf3',                  100, 100, 100 from dual union all
       select 4, 'asdf4', cast(null as number),   0,  10 from dual
     )
--  End of TEST data (not part of solution!) SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   id, description, pay1, pay2, pay3,
           1
         + case when nvl(pay2, -1) not in (nvl(pay1, -1)) 
                then 1 else 0 end
         + case when nvl(pay3, -1) not in (nvl(pay1, -1), nvl(pay2, -1))
                then 1 else 0 end
                                       as distinct_pays
from     inputs
order by id   --  if needed
;

ID DESCRIPTION     PAY1    PAY2    PAY3 DISTINCT_PAYS
-- ------------ ------- ------- ------- -------------
 1 asdf1             10      20      10             2
 2 asdf2              0      10      20             3
 3 asdf3            100     100     100             1
 4 asdf4                      0      10             3

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: You do realise that there are 8 pay columns. Your case statement is going to have to cater for a VERY large number of comparisons (which is why I used union btw). Let's see them!

Comment: @Bohemian -  Yes, I realize that. The comparisons are trivial; the bottleneck (in most cases) will be accessing the rows repeatedly. Besides: any kind of counting does pretty much the same comparisons (how do you expect the Oracle engine to `count distinct` values anyway?)

Comment: oracle does it using O(n log n) efficiency, but you must use O(n2) efficiency because that's how many comparisons must be made using case statements

Comment: @Bohemian - actually it is O(n^2) (check your math). And editorial comments like "crappy" are best left out in writing - although I will admit I am also guilty of that sometimes. And n, here, is 8, not millions. So in fact it is still O(1) (a constant number of comparisons).

Comment: `nvl(pay1, -1`) assumes that -1 is not a valid value for `pay1`.  If you don't know that for sure, better to convert to a `VARCHAR2` and use a string value for nulls.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - I haven't heard of negative payments. With that said, I thought I saw where the OP said payments were integers between 0 and 999, but now I see there was no mention of 0. There is mention of "maximum 999" so if negative payments was a worry (which I doubt), then I would rather use 1001 as a marker for null - so as not to convert everything to `varchar2`. But the worry is that in the future payments may be greater than 999 even if they are not today. I doubt that in the future "negative payments" will be any more likely than today.

Comment: It doesn't seem too unlikely that negative payments represent credit or income.

Comment: @mathguy I work with Oracle e-Business Suite and negative payments are quite common.  They're called "credit memos" and they're issued for things like returns and refunds.  Maybe I wouldn't model them as a negative value in the pay column, but neither would I create a table with eight "pay" columns in the first place.  When that's your starting data model, I'd say you're in the realm of "anything is possible".

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - OK. In any case, I would look for a `number` solution, to avoid the non-trivial overhead of converting every number into a string. I could use 0.1 if all the payments are integers. Or 0.001 if in the future it may be possible to record dollars and cents. Or 0.000001. Some kind of number that is unlikely to ever be present in the "real" data - not a different data type.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - and also, for full disclosure - I don't work in IT and never had. I am now retired, from other industries, and learning Oracle on my own; most of what I said, regarding "real-life use", is at best an educated guess. Keep that in mind for the future!   :-)

Comment: Fair enough.  It's simple to use 9.9999E+100 or something like that.  And I wasn't trying to difficult or condescending.  I respect you and the many excellent answers you post on this site.

Comment: This appears to work for me!  The 'case when' method was in the back of my mind but didn't quite know how to implement it.  Thank you!  Btw there are no negative values in these columns, and virtually zero chance of >999 values based on the nature of the data.  Also '0' does count as a value the same as 10 or 100, and is distinct from NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be:

1. Start with your initial table without the column `#uniquePays`.
2. Unpivot your table.

From this

```
ID   Description   Pay1    Pay2   Pay3 
1    asdf1         10      20     10
```

Make this:

```
ID seq Description Pay
 1   1 asdf1       10
 1   2 asdf1       20
 1   3 asdf1       10
```

3. From the unpivoted table, run a SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Pay)
4. Re-pivot the table, adding the COUNT(DISTINCT Pay).

Will this do, or do you need an exemplary script? I've been posting quite a bit about pivoting and un-pivoting lately .... seems to be a popular need :-]

Marco the Sane

Comment: Count ignores nulls - so for ID 4, that would report 2 unique values rather than 3? This also may not be very efficient for a large table.

Comment: I had a feeling pivots would be where this is headed, this makes sense to me.  Example script would be helpful to get me on track, but either way I'll be brushing up on my pivoting skills! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can write on insert *trigger* or *stored procedure* to count total number of unique value for each insert statement and update in unique column.